# Problema con querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy intentado coger con querySelectorAll todos los botones que tienen una misma clase. Para ver si los almacena correctamente en un array estoy intentando visualizarlo por consola pero me dice que el array esta vacío. He probado a poner cualquier tipo de clase, id o etiqueta y no me coge nada, siempre dice que el array esta vacío.
El código resumido es el siguiente:

```js
const addToShoppingCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn_añadir');
console.log(addToShoppingCartButtons);
```

```html
    <div class="piezas">
            <div>
                <img class="pieza_img" src="imagenes/recambios/cargador.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="nombre_pieza">
                <p>Beikell cargador USB de doble puerto</p>
            </div>
            <div class="botones_pieza">
                <div class="botones"><button class="btn_añadir"><span class="material-icons">add</span></button></div>
                <div class="botones"><button class="btn_quitar"><span class="material-icons">remove</span></button></div>
            </div>
            <div class="stock">
                <p>En Stock</p>
            </div>
            <div class="precio_pieza">
                <p>6.59€/ud</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Al abrir la consola me dice que el array esta vacio, incluso poniendo las etiquetas p o div.
La consola me saca esto:
NodeList []

Alguien sabe por que puede ser? He probado en otros documentos menos tediosos y funciona sin problema.

Comment: probé el código en stackblitz y obtiene los ítems sin problemas

Comment: Lo acabo de probar ahi y tambien me funciona, en cambio abriendo el proyecto de VSCode en Chrome o Firefox sigue sin funcionarme

Comment: Que raro, lo único que se me ocurre es que el js no este linkeado al html, pero es raro igual por que si no tendría que imprimir nada en consola, el código que tenes en vscode es exactamente igual al que publicaste?

Comment: recomendamos no utilizar acentos en el código fuente de cualquier lenguaje.

Comment: ¿No será que tienes el js en el head de tu página HTML?

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado. Como decía un comentario, tenia el enlace al js en el head y no en el body. No sabia que eso podía influir. Ahora ya funciona correctamente. Muchas gracias a todos los que habéis intentado ayudarme.

Comment: En el fragmento de código funciona correctamente; como dice @PabloLozano, tal vez estás tratando de cargar los botones antes de que aparezcan en el DOM y debas colocar el código _Javascript_ antes de `<body>` o ponerlo en una función que se ejecute hasta haber cargado el DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas probable es que esté relacionado con la "ñ" en el nombre. Te recomiendo evitar el uso de caracteres especiales como la "ñ" porque genera muchos errores y en algunos lenguajes son inválidos.

También puedes intentar usar método document.getElementsByClassName()

Answer (score 0):

Probar ejecutar el script.js al final del HTMl. Ya que, al momento de ejecutar aun no exite el elemento al que llamas y retorma un NodeList vacio. tambien se puede usar un setTimeout(funcion, intervalo)

```
window.setTimeout(()=>{
   fichas = document.querySelectorAll('.ficha');
   console.log(fichas)
}, 1000)
```